# Can't show properties of a model in .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a website using C# .NET. I created a model named "Model1" that has looks like this -

```
 Public class model1{
  [key]
  Public int model1id {get; set; }
  Public User AppUser {get; set;}
 }
```

And the User class looked like so -

```
Public class User{
 [key]
 Public int UserId,
 Public string FName 
}
```

At the time I am adding entries to model1, I make sure the AppUser field has a value -

```
model1 modelToAdd = new model1{
AppUser = _db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == LoggedInUser)
}
```

And sure enough, when I look at the model1 table in the server explorer, I see a column named "User_UserId" and it is not null and set to the value of the user that was logged in at the time the record was created.

However, when I try to display the first name of the user corresponding to Model1 in a .aspx file -

```
<%#:Item.AppUser.FName%>
```

I get a null pointer exception (object reference wasn't set to an instance of the object). Am I missing some thing?

Comment: Why do you have a colon ? <%#:Item.AppUser.FName%>

Comment: Other field displays work with the colon. Should it not be there?

Comment: please post the code where it is databinding, aspx and code behind code